# Find the domain of definition for this quasilinear equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

$$ x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= 2u \qquad (1)$$

find, in explicit form, the solution of (1) which satisfies the condition:
$$ u =x^3 \quad  \text{on} \quad   y=x+1 \qquad (2)$$
In which region of the $xy$-plane is $u(x, y)$ uniquely determined by the equation (1) with the condition (2)?

My working: 
So I used the method of characteristics to answer the first part and attained implicitly and then explicitly:
$$(se^t, \,(s+1)e^t,\, s^3e^{2t})$$
$$u(x,y) =\frac{x^3}{y-x}$$

My difficulty comes in finding the domain of definition. My understanding is that it is not unique when the initial curve crosses a characteristic. I calculated the Jacobian, because when that is zero, the initial curve should be tangential to a characteristic, i.e.
$$ J= e^{2t} = {(y-x)^2},$$
which equals zero when $x=y$.
So is the solution unique when $y>x$ or perhaps when $y<x$?

I am not quite sure though, where to go from here? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: correction made to my working.
I still do not understand how to find where the solution is unique.

Comment: You don't show enough intermediate steps in your calculus to see where exactly is your difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= 2u \qquad (1)$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{2u}$$
From $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$\frac{y}{x}=c_1$$
From $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{2u}$ :
$$\frac{u}{x^2}=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE :
$\quad\frac{u}{x^2}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

$$u(x,y)=x^2F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the boundary condition.

CONDITION :

$u(x,x+1)=x^3=x^2F\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$
$$F\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)=x$$
Let $X=\frac{x+1}{x}\quad ; \quad x=\frac{1}{X-1}$
$$F(X)=\frac{1}{X-1}$$
The function $F(X)$ is determined.

We put it into the general solution where $X=\frac{y}{x}$, thus $F(X)=\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}-1}=\frac{x}{y-x}$

The particular solution which satisfies the boundary condition is :
$$u(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{y-x}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I made an error at the start by forgetting the u on the RHS. The part that I don't understand though, is specifically where this solution is unique?

Comment: On the line $y=x\:,\quad u$ is infinite. So the trajectories starting from any point on $y=x+1$ cannot cross $y=x$ and cannot go into the region $y<x$. Thus in the region $y<x$ the solutions are not uniquely determined by the given boundary condition.